# I have used SelectBeforeUpdate but every time i persist a detached object without any changes hibernate is saving with column value with null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have started using hibernate and im not a pro. I am trying to implement an example to turn a detached object to persistence object .
I am getting this error.
I have used SelectBeforeUpdate but every time i persist a detached object without any changes hibernate is saving with column value with null.

Entity class is :

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SelectBeforeUpdate;

@Entity
@Table (name="USER_DETACHED")
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@DynamicUpdate
public class UserDetails {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;

    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
}

 > ##  Main Method is: I have tried using generatedValue alone and with strategy auto also ... it didnt work ##


public class TestCrud {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user= new UserDetails();
        Configuration configuration = newConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build(); 
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        user = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class,1);
        System.out.println(user.getUserId() +   "         " + user.getUserName());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

My StackTrace is:

```
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
    INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
    INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
    INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe]
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=hr, password=****}
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:46 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
    INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000261: Table found: HR.USER_DETACHED
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [userid, username]
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
    INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [sys_c008436]
    Jul 05, 2015 10:44:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
    INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
    Hibernate: select userdetail0_.userId as userId1_0_0_, userdetail0_.userName as userName2_0_0_ from USER_DETACHED userdetail0_ where userdetail0_.userId=?
    1         Sandeep
    Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
    Hibernate: insert into USER_DETACHED (userName, userId) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: The 'StackTrace' you have posted is not a stack trace, but looks more like log entries. Please post the actual stack trace that you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified @Id @GeneratedValue to generate primary key.
As you know hibernate it self will assign the primary key id value into the database right.
So in this case if we call save() then it will insert the record into the database normally as it checks based on the pk only
It will set its own generated value to primary key and default value(in your case null) for other columns too when the entity is flushed to the database

Note that in your log it is showing below which means it is generating new pk

> Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual

Comment: Is there any way to stop adding null values to the database...? If i'm not wrong  selectBeforeUpdate annotation actually checks the table content and add if there is a change. If i had to use auto generated primary key and want use select before update is there any way to do it. May be by changing the strategy property?

Comment: @Sandeep , yes in the same example if session.saveOrUpdate() is used it will update the existing record instead of creating new record in database.